# Correct Graph API to manage Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Am I misinterpreting this -- see image?

I go to documentation for managing Azure AD B2C, it tells me to use Azure AD Graph API, **not** Microsoft Graph API.

Then I click the link to go to Azure AD Graph API, it tells me to use the Microsoft Graph API, **not** the Azure AD Graph API.

[image]

Two questions:

1. What do I use to manage users in Azure AD B2C? Microsoft Graph API or Azure AD Graph API?
2. What's the easiest and most painless way to interact with the Graph API I should be using -- based on your answer to question #1? Can I use a tool like Postman? If I'm not mistaken, these are RESTful APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I use to manage users in Azure AD B2C? Microsoft Graph API or
>   Azure AD Graph API?

As the document noted, **you must use Azure AD Graph API**. Azure AD Graph API can manage users in a B2C tenant (set local accounts, sign in names), but Microsoft Graph API cannot do this for now. Although Microsoft Graph closing the gap with Azure AD Graph, but it still cannot have some capabilities as Azure AD Graph API.

> What's the easiest and most painless way to interact with the Graph
>   API I should be using -- based on your answer to question #1? Can I
>   use a tool like Postman? If I'm not mistaken, these are RESTful APIs.

Absolutely, you can just use Azure AD Graph API for Azure AD B2C for now.

By the way, if you want to know which API is more fit for Azure AD. It's hard to say. Sometimes it depends on what scenario you're in.  There is a sheet of Gaps between Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph:

[image]

Both two type APIs can be used in Postman.

Fore more details about Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph , you can refer to [**this Blog**](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph).

Comment: You can also use the [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/) app to interact through the Azure AD Graph API with the Azure AD B2C directory.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett. Yep, the examples in official documents all used Azure AD Graph Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. A follow up question: I’m trying to migrate users from my DB to Azure AD B2C which is why I’m interested using the Graph API. All users that I’m migrating used social logins such as LinkedIn, Google and Facebook. How would I specify in the Azure B2C directory the social provider users used to register and sign into my app? In my existing DB, I have an identifier that indicates the social provider. Not sure how Azure AD B2C stores and handles this information. Thank you for your help!